# Use different versions of jar for maven: one for JDK 8 and another for JDK 11

Tags: java, java-11, java-module

We are testing out compilation with JDK 11.  In our pom.xml, we have a dependency on xml-apis:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
```

The code compiles fine with JDK 8, but errors out in JDK 11 since most of the classes in xml-apis are also in JDK 11, and this error happens:
**The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: unnamed, java.xml**

Is there a way in the pom.xml to have a dependency used conditionally, like whether a jdk11.compile property is set?

Comment: as a general suggestion, you might look for an upgraded version from the libraries to support JDK-11 themselves and that would be much cleaner.

Comment: What if you remove `xml-apis` dependency at all? JDK 8 already has all the classes that are provided by `xml-apis`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Maven profiles to add a specific dependency only when a precise jdk version is detected:

```
<profile>
    <id>Java 8</id>
    <activation>
        <jdk>1.8</jdk>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>…</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

You can also use custom properties to activate a profile. See Maven guide for more details:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html